# I have a PreferenceFragment, how can I make it it's own Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I already have made a class that extends `PreferenceFragment` to display my apps preferences. It works, but I decided I should make the fragment appear in a new activity so that the user can back out of it. Right now, it just gets swapped into the main fragment and displayed. How can I simply make an activity that displays the entire `PreferenceFragment`? There is no layout defined for the `Fragment` since it's a `PreferenceFragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new activity that contains one fragment. Insert the preferences fragment in it. Here is a copy of what I use in my project.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity{

    public final static String SETTINGS_NATIVE_IGNORE = "pref_native_ignore";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id)
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

then the xml for it

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="...SettingsActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment
android:id="@+id/preferences_fragment"
android:name="...fragment.PreferencesFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_preferences"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the preferences fragment

```
public class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {


    public PreferencesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```